# MSSQL Maximum number of statistics per table

Tags: sql, sql-server

As a general rule of thumb, is there a maximum/sensible number of statistics for an individual table on MS SQL Server?

I have a DB which I've noticed has over 100 statistics on a table with 6 indexes.

Comment: What do *you* mean by "statistics per table"?

Comment: Is that excluding the column stats?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I mean if I drill down in SSMS to the statistics folder for a given table, I see 119 statistics starting with names like _dta_stat_ and _WA_Sys_.

Comment: @ShawnMelton - no it's not.  TBH, I didn't know the difference, I've just counted and there are 96 column statistics, table has 100 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto-created statistics ("WA") are created for columns specified as `WHERE` clause predicates that are not already indexed to help estimate row counts for better execution plans.

The "dta" stats are generated SSMS advisor tools. These hypothetical stats may have been left behind from a tuning exercise that wasn't completed. See [this page from Brent Ozar's sp_Blitz](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/hypothetical-indexes-index-tuning-wizard/) for a script to identify and drop these.

The max number of stats is 30,000 according the [maximum capacity specifications documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).